# MySQL Desc Limit is not limiting the return?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a "collective posts" page, which is where all of your friends posts would show up. Im not talking about `$_POST` but posts like status updates on facebook. My code works some what, but the only problem is that it is returning more than three results, im not sure  why though. I have looked around but I have not had any luck.

The Code:

```
        $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $frnd_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_one, user_two FROM friends WHERE user_one='$my_id' OR user_two='$my_id'");
        while($run_frnd = mysql_fetch_array($frnd_query)) {
            $user_one = $run_frnd['user_one'];
            $user_two = $run_frnd['user_two'];
            if($user_one == $my_id){
                $user = $user_two;
            } else {
                $user = $user_one;
            }



              $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id=$user ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 3");

              while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                ?>
                    <div class="span4">
                      <h3><a href="<?php echo username_from_user_id($user); ?>"><?php echo first_name_from_user_id($user), ' ', last_name_from_user_id($user) ?></a></h3>
                       <h8><?php echo date('F j, Y', strtotime($row['timestamp'])) ,' at ', date('h:i A', strtotime($row['timestamp'])); ?></h8>
                      <p><?php echo $row['content']; ?></p>
                      <p><a class="btn" href="#">View Reactions &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->

                <?php
              }



        }//While Run_frnd

        ?>
```

I've tried multiple things, but no luck. Also, when it comes to the new PDO what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
JOIN (SELECT user_one AS user_id
      FROM friends
      WHERE user_two = '$my_id'
      UNION DISTINCT
      SELECT user_two AS user_id
      FROM friends
      WHERE user_one = '$my_id') u
USING (user_id)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 3
```

See my [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de5d2/2)

Comment: What is the `post p` mean, should it just be `FROM posts`

Comment: When I started writing the query, I thought I might use an ON clause instead of USING, so I gave it a short alias. You can leave it out if you want.

Comment: That seems to work, but it is only showing me results from only one friend? How would I show the 3 latest posts from my friends

Comment: This will show the 3 latest posts from all friends. If it's only showing one friend, he made all 3 latest posts.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason, it is displaying the last 3 posts, but showing them coming from only user, like it is showing posts from both users 2 and 3 but the first and last names are apearing as user 3's name?

Comment: Can you create a sqlfiddle with some sample data?

Comment: There's no `friends` table in the Schema panel (the left one). And you can't put PHP in the SQL panel, just put the query (replace PHP variables with their values).

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id=$user ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 3")
```

Is being run within this `while` loop:

```
while($run_frnd = mysql_fetch_array($frnd_query)) {
```

And so you're going to get up to 3 results *per* friend rather than up to 3 total.

You can get around it by doing:

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id=$user ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 3");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

  $i = !isset($i) ? 1 : $i + 1;

    ?>
                <div class="span4">
                  <h3><a href="<?php echo username_from_user_id($user); ?>"><?php echo first_name_from_user_id($user), ' ', last_name_from_user_id($user) ?></a></h3>
                   <h8><?php echo date('F j, Y', strtotime($row['timestamp'])) ,' at ', date('h:i A', strtotime($row['timestamp'])); ?></h8>
                  <p><?php echo $row['content']; ?></p>
                  <p><a class="btn" href="#">View Reactions &raquo;</a></p>
                </div><!--/span-->

    <?php

  if (3 == $i)
  {
    break 2;
  }  

}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Is there a way to limit it to just 3 total?

Comment: Use a single joined query, not a nested loop.

Comment: Can you give me an example of that please? Im not sure if I follow?

Comment: This seems to work, but how wolud I show the next 3 results,I would have to be a new `while()` because of the style of the output area

Comment: You just said you wanted it limited to 3 results. Is it now 6?

Comment: No, if i want to display the three after those 3, how would I go upon doing that? Because due to the way I am outputting the content, I can only display three at a time.

Comment: Well kinda, I need to display the next 3 in a new while.